# Any way to catch potentially undefined variables in Python?

Tags: python, variable-declaration

Although I really enjoy working with Python, I'm a big fan languages that enforce variable declaration before use, because it catches silly spelling mistakes in variables before the code is even run.

Is there any utility that can scan python files and warn you if it thinks a variable is potentially undeclared?

Comment: apart from IDEs that have such features (e.g., PyCharm)?

Comment: PyCharm does this to an extent. Tool recs are off topic for SO though.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Thanks - where should I post this question?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would be a good start. I don't know their rules though, so make sure you read them first to make sure.

Comment: Won't you get a `NameError` exception?

Comment: This is a very hard problem to solve in general. For instance, consider `if val: a = 1; else: pass; print(a)`. Whether `a` is defined or not depends on `val`.

Comment: I will, but I'll get it while the code is running and then I'll need to debug and figure out what went wrong. Also, the nature of the system that the code is running on (embedded system) means that when the code is running, exceptions aren't printed to the system log. I'm looking for something that will highlight potential issues at "compile time"

Comment: if im understanding correctly you want to have a pop up when typing in a variable name that you have already used to appear and enter it for you? if this is the case you can download visual studio and install the python extension

Comment: @MorganThrapp I've just tried PyCharm and it is absolutely fantastic - does exactly what I want and does really good static analysis of the Python code. Shame you won't put it as an answer!

Comment: @AmrBekhit PyCharm can also interpret [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Keep in mind, though, that they're not enforced whatsoever. They're just hints, nothing more. Still, they can also help you to catch problems before runtime.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Regarding closing the question, although technically, softwarerecs might be a more suitable place to post it, as this question is very closely tied to a specific programming language, I'm far more likely to get useful answers here because it'll be exposed to far more users of the language.

Comment: @AmrBekhit All of that is true, but it doesn't make the question on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @MorganThrapp and @Ev. Kounis in the comments, [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) does this really well. It has a fantastic static code analyser that will analyse your Python code and highlight potential errors and warnings, even going so far as analysing conditional branches and warning you if there is the potential for a variable to be uninitialised.

I ran it through my existing code and it immediately highlighted errors that I'd had to track down manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure Python utility which I know of which can perform the function you want.  However, dynamic variable declaration can be used as part of your program flow the the `try...except` structure:

```
if some_input:
    a = 5

try:
    print a
except NameError:
    Do_something
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm looking for a utility that will do this for me BEFORE my code runs.

Comment: This is a tool rec question. It should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I see it as an XY problem and chose to post one possible solution

Comment: How is this XY? It's explicitly a tool rec according to OP and OP has stated that this won't work for them.

Comment: @MorganThrapp, usually when questions ask about getting around designed features of Python, they can be solved by better coding practices (an example of an XY problem).